# Using Two Themes - One for Main Site, One for Ecommerce

Tags: multisite, themes

I have a question that I haven’t been able to find a great answer to. Hoping you guys can help me out.

I am in the process of rebuilding our company website. I have a WP theme picked out that I really love (Create from ThemeTrust). I want to use that as the theme for our entire site, except the ecommerce pages. I am hoping to use Shopify as our ecommerce platform, with a Shopify theme. Create already has a Woocommerce theme built in, but I’d like to use Shopify because of their retail POS and mobile sales capabilities.

So my question is, can I use one theme (Create) as the base for most of the site, then use a Shopify theme for the ecommerce section of the site? My goal is to not have to use a subdomain for the site…ie (shop.domain.com). I’d like to keep it all together, (domain.com/shop).

Any information/advice on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: you Shopify theme is a theme for your wordpress or it is another website?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices:

1. (best choice) Using a wordpress in is own folder:

   1. Move you "Wordpress" to a subfolder. (you can [use this tutorial](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory))
   2. Install your Shopify into his own directory too.
   3. See result :

   [image]

   By using this method, your wordpress will take the main domain(localhost for me) except for the "real folder" in your site. IF you want to add "/private_site" and using a custom PHP, you could do too.
2. (bad choice) play with `.htaccess`

   1. Create a subfolder in your wordpress (in root)
   2. stop redirect for this "folder" 
      ex.: `RewriteRule ^(others)($|/) - [L]`

I recommend the first one because it is easy and avoid to add multiple non-wordpress in his folder.

Answer (score 1):

When building a page, WordPress looks in the option table in the database which theme to use. This read action can be intercepted, as you can see from the fact that you can [live preview themes](http://www.themelab.com/preview-wordpress-theme-live-site/) ([more extensively with a plugin](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/theme-preview/)).

So, if you want to build something like this yourself, you would have to dive into the matter. It's a bit too much to detail that out here. Or you could use a plugin like [Multiple Themes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/).